# Laravel cannot store data into database

Tags: php, laravel, controller

wanting to insert this data to database with laravel controller, but there's no error message and it seems the data won't be stored.

this is my controller function

```
public function store3(){
        $time = new Time;
        $time->leaderboard_id = '1';
        $time->user_id = '1';
        $time->event_id = '1';
        $time->time = '1';
        $time->avg = '1';
        $time->save();
        return $this->scramble3(0);
    }
```

this is my migration table

```
Schema::create('time', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->float("time");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('leaderboard_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('events_id');
            $table->float('avg');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('time', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate("cascade");
            $table->foreign('leaderboard_id')->references('id')->on('leaderboards')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate("cascade");
            $table->foreign('events_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate("cascade");
        });
    }
```

my model code

```
class Time extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "time";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'leaderboard_id',
        'events_id',
        'time',
        'avg'
    ];

    public function User(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'User_id','id');
    }
    public function Leaderboard(){
        return $this->hasOne(Leadeboard::class, 'Leaderboard_id','id');
    }

    public function Event(){
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'Events_id','id');
    }

    }
```

can anyone help what's wrong with it?

Comment: how do you know this controller method is even running at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
public function store3(){
    $time = new Time;
    $time->leaderboard_id = 1;
    $time->user_id = 1;
    $time->event_id = 1;
    $time->time = 1;
    $time->avg = 1;
    $time->save();
    return $this->scramble3(0);
}
```

Your schema is `$table->unsignedBigInteger` and `$table->float` but you passed data as string `$time->leaderboard_id = '1';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$time->event_id = '1';
```

should be

```
 $time->events_id = '1'; # 'event' <> 'events'
```

---

Use `try{} catch{}` in future for debugs

```
public function store3(){
    try {
        $time = new Time;
        $time->leaderboard_id = '1';
        $time->user_id = '1';
        $time->events_id = '1';
        $time->time = '1';
        $time->avg = '1';
        $time->save();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->scramble3(0);
}
```

Comment: That's the only error in this. check with `try{} catch{}`

Comment: add `$time->id= 555;` and check

Comment: try catch didn't output anything, i will try your next suggestion and update you immediately

Comment: nope still not stored into the db

Comment: Open your database, and change all field to `varchar(255)` and then try to save

Comment: should i do it with migration first or directly into database?

Comment: directly in DB.(for testing only)

Comment: i dont think thats possible bc some ids are foreign keys from other table

Comment: It's okay. You can run migration again by dropping that table. Don't think about migration. It will work

Comment: pardon? i don't think I understand what you are trying to do here..

Comment: You are passing strings to integer columns. Therefore remove single quote from every values. Then try again